# Line break is not recognized for header when importing CSV

Tags: ssis

I have a bunch of CSV files that I need to import via. SSIS. I think ( not 100% sure ) that the files origin from a unix like device.

I have download the files via. C# from an FTP.

The files look like this when opened in Notepad++

[image]

The delimiters in the files is comma ,

The header use a new line char which is LF

But all data rows use CR LF as new line char.

The encoding of the file is UTF-8 as show in Notepad++ below.

[image]

When I create the flat file connection manager in SSIS I choose UTF-8 as codepage and LF as header row delimiter.

[image]

But in the preview diaglog the header row  delimiter is not recognized and the first datarow is used as column headers as well.

[image]

I have not managed to understand what I am missing and is wondering if it is the codepage and  the source of the files that is tricking me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily skip header row by setting the "*Hearder rows to skip:*" to 1.

Comment: Hmm, That migth be a solution that I had not thought of. I can map them manually. Will give it a go.
If anyone have a solution where the header row is not skipped then please come forward :)